# Designing a database and querying with mySQL - Not sure if i modeled this correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm new to database design so I'm kinda unsure if I'm doing things right here.

I'm creating a database for a fake scooter rental service. Here are the events that would be affecting my database:

If a new customer enters store:

```
Store customer info,

If they were referred:

    Make note of name of referrer
```

If previous customer enters:

```
Retrieve previous customer info,

**If this customer has an un-returned scooter, they can't borrow another
```

If a customer is renting a scooter, keep track of:

```
Date/hour of borrow,

Date/hour of return,

How much paid, 

Freeform notes that are categorized, ie Issues while scooter is returned or when used
```

When scooter is returned:

```
When it was returned,

Is return late, 

Is scooter damaged, 

Additional fees for damage / late return
```

Queries I'm gonna be making to the database:

All people who have flags,

All available scooters,

All borrowed scooters,

All late scooters,

People with top 5 most referrals,

For a person, show all the times that person has borrowed a scooter,

For an instance of a borrow, show any additional fees, and

All manufacturers of scooters

Here is what I came up with (not an actual diagram yet, just the different tables and relationships), not sure at all if this is on the right track:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft7yx.jpg

[image: Typed out tables]

Comment: In order to critique a Schema, I need to see the main queries.

Comment: I believe I already listed them in the op

Answer (score 0):

Right. There are some issues with your design. The idea in SQL DB's so to "normalize" the information, meaning not have data duplicated. That's one thing to have in mind, the other, is that you have to think in terms of "entities" and "relationships" between those entities, as opposed to objects and actions. Let's see:

```
CUSTOMER
 -name
 -email

SCOOTER
 -manufacturer
 -model

RENTALS
 -customerID
 -scooterID
 -startDate
 -plannedEndDate
 -actualEndDate
```

So "RENTALS" here is a many-to-many table, relating a customer that can have many scooters rented, and a scooter that will have many customers over its lifetime. customerID and scooterID can be the auto ROWID from MySQL, or you can set them explicitly in a specific ID field.

From this setup you can get a lot of info by designing queries:

Is the scooter available?

```
SELECT * FROM RENTALS WHERE scooterID = X AND plannedEndDate > DATE()
```

Meaning, the scooter is rented and will be returned at some point in the future.

Do we have scooters late?

```
SELECT * FROM RENTALS WHERE plannedEndDate < DATE() AND actualEndDate = NULL
```

Meaning, scooters that were supposed to already be returned, but haven't.

And so on. Hope that helps!

Comment: 1st select:  `INDEX(scooterID, plannedEndDate)`; 2nd: `INDEX(actualEndDate, plannedEndDate)`.  _Bug_:  Don't do `= NULL`; instead do `IS NULL`.

Comment: This does help a lot, but shouldn't SCOOTER be the many-to-many instead of RENTALS? Shouldn't a row in RENTALS only be specific to one instance of a rental?

Comment: A row in rentals is specific to a 'rent event' in this design... the row relates the info of all the entities involved in the event, currently 1 customer + 1 scooter.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. So, does CUSTOMER have a many-to-many relationship with both RENTALS and SCOOTER?

Comment: CUSTOMER has a many-many relationship with SCOOTER, meaning, 1 customer can rent many scooters, each being a row in rental, and a scooter can be rented multiple times, each being row in rental. In this design, RENTALS is not an entity, but a relationship, that relates scooter and customer. Tables allow a direct connection only 1-many, to do a many-many, you need an in-between table, in this case, rentals

Comment: ah I didn't know that last part.

Comment: So how would it look in an ER diagram? What symbols are going out of the RENTALS table?

Comment: Or is RENTALS represented by a diamond with no symbols going out of it, and crow's feet coming out of both CUSTOMER and SCOOTER, both of which are connected to RENTALS?

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember haha haven't used diagrams in many years

Comment: So these tables are in 2nd normal form I'm assuming?

Comment: Yes. But the concept is easy: if it can be repeated or it can vary, put it in a separate table.

Comment: so RENTAL has a composite key right? The 2 primary keys would be customerID and scooterID

Comment: Could be, you can also use a sep key if needed. This really depends on the indices you'll create for your queries

Answer (score 0):

Don't have any columns that are 'plural'.  Instead, have another table that links back to this table.  Examples:  Referrals, Borrow Instances.

"People with top 5 most referrals," will be *much* easier to query from the extra table mentioned above.

What says whether a Scooter is currently in use?  Perhaps Scooters.Availability ?  Note that you will probably need to insert/update more than one table when a Scooter is 'taken' and when it is 'returned'.

"All late scooters" may be difficult to determine from the suggested schema.  You *may* need to have another table that focuses on a 'sale'.  That is, a row is added when a scooter is borrowed; perhaps things are changed over time; and the row is marked 'complete' (probably not deleted) when the scooter is 'returned'.  Note this table provides easy info to someone looking at the 'money' that 'changes hands'.  It may also provide a source for "Past rented scooters", which I criticized above.

So, I suggest about 3 more tables, and move a few columns into those tables.

**Referrals**...

You should *not* try to put an array into a column.  It is messy, clumsy, etc.  Instead, create another table (`Referrals`) and have it link back to the main table (`Customers`).

When you have a "many to 1" mapping ('many' referrals for 'one' customer):

```
Customer:  customer_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, etc
    -- no mention of "referrals"
CREATE TABLE Referrals (
    customer_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- the referree
    name,   -- who referred
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This allows for many 'names' to refer one 'customer_id'.

If "referrals" are necessarily other Customers, then you have a many-to-many table:

```
Customer:  customer_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, etc
    -- no mention of "referrals"
CREATE TABLE Referrals (
    ee_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- customer_id of the referee
    er_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- customer_id of the referer
    PRIMARY KEY(ee_id, er_id),
    INDEX(er_id, ee_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: So the tables you suggest adding along with what Sergio wrote above, is Referrals, Sales, and Borrows? Why is Borrows necessary if I already have a Rentals table? And in addition, if one of the columns of my Customer table is "referrals", what would be the type if I'm linking the Referrals table to the Customer table's referrals field?

Comment: @user10366926 -- Oops, Borrows, and Sales are the same.  1:1 is _usually_ not a good idea.  Consider combining Borrow and Return into a single table, with `NULL` for the return info.  (This is a suggestion, not a 'requirement'.)

Comment: @user10366926 - Yes, the Referals table would be a list of referals, linking to Customers (many:one).  If Referals only come from Customers, then it is a many:many table relating customers to customers.

Comment: So when writing my SQL table with CREATE TABLE, what is the type I put for referrals?

Comment: OK, I provided specifics on the _table_ Referrals.  Do not try to put an array in a column.

Comment: Ok so the relationships are: CUSTOMER is one-to-many with REFERRALS, REFERRALS is many-to-one with CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER is also many-to-many with SCOOTER and vice versa. CUSTOMER is also many-to-many with RENTALS, and vice versa. Finally, RENTALS is many-to-many with SCOOTER too?

Comment: I probably would try to avoid the 3-way many:many (customer--rental--scooter).  I would look at the queries that need to join those tables to decide which two of the three many:many tables to make.  So far, "times a person has borrowed a scooter" seems to be the only join needed.

Comment: Why avoid the 3-way many:many? And what do you mean by decide which two to make? Are you saying only 2 out of those 3 tables should be even made? The query "times a person has borrowed a scooter" needs me to do inner join on rows from the CUSTOMER and RENTALS tables, right?

Comment: @user10366926 - A standard philosophy in database design is to avoid redundancy.  3 many:many _felt like_ redundancy.  But maybe I am wrong.  Go ahead and do the 3 many:many; re-assess it later.